How to open local app with HTML using ActiveXObject?
I want open PyCharm project with html and js
First i try to open the notepad
this is my code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="f()">Click me</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function f() {
            WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            WshShell.Run("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe", 1, false);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>


ActiveX is Internet Explorer specific object only, and usually not allowed on web pages.

Firstly, using ActiveXObject to open a local application from HTML is possible but it only works in Internet Explorer (IE) and is limited to Windows environments.
Secondly,in JavaScript strings, backslashes () need to be escaped with another backslash. Therefore, C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe should be written as C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe.
So, replace your code with the below:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Open Notepad with ActiveX</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="f()">Click me</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function f() {
            try {
                var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                WshShell.Run("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe", 1, false);
            } catch (e) {
                alert("ActiveXObject failed: " + e.message);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

